# Memory overhead of maps in Go

Tags: hashmap, go

map[byte]byte{0:10} should be using least 2 bytes, one for value and one per key. But as each hashmap implmentation, there is also a hidden cost per item.
What is the memory overhead per entry in Go maps in both gccgo and gc?

Comment: This is an implementation detail.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about that implementation detail.

Comment: Ah, I see. A Go map currently is just hash table.

Comment: Yes, and the question is what is the memory overhead per entry in that hashtable's implementations in gccgo and gc.

Comment: I think they use hash tables with 32 bit hashes and linear probing. Have a look at the [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/hashmap.c)

Comment: The hash itself is a uintptr, which should be 8 bytes on amd64. There also a byte data[1]. This gives 9 bytes extra per entry as the lower bound, but still not an exact answer.

Comment: Too localized to be sensible. This parameter is free to change even between minor (bug fix) releases, so what's the point to ask this? If one is about writing a program which should employ a hash map of immense size, write a sample and *measure.* And note that in a case like this, more problems might come from the GC, not merely from the size of a hash map.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a cross-platform reimplementation of Nick's program. It includes changes where I think it was flawed. It also adds more measured data points.

**Note**: To allow for a wider "entries" range, the measured map bellow is `map[int16]byte`.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
        "unsafe"
)

func Alloc() uint64 {
        var stats runtime.MemStats
        runtime.GC()
        runtime.ReadMemStats(&stats)
        return stats.Alloc - uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(hs[0]))*uint64(cap(hs))
}

var hs = []*map[int16]byte{}

func main() {
        hs := []*map[int16]byte{}
        n := 1000
        before := Alloc()
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                h := map[int16]byte{}
                hs = append(hs, &h)
        }
        after := Alloc()
        emptyPerMap := float64(after-before) / float64(n)
        fmt.Printf("Bytes used for %d empty maps: %d, bytes/map %.1f\n", n, after-before, emptyPerMap)
        hs = nil

        k := 1
        for p := 1; p < 16; p++ {
                before = Alloc()
                for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                        h := map[int16]byte{}
                        for j := 0; j < k; j++ {
                                h[int16(j)] = byte(j)
                        }
                        hs = append(hs, &h)
                }
                after = Alloc()
                fullPerMap := float64(after-before) / float64(n)
                fmt.Printf("Bytes used for %d maps with %d entries: %d, bytes/map %.1f\n", n, k, after-before, fullPerMap)
                fmt.Printf("Bytes per entry %.1f\n", (fullPerMap-emptyPerMap)/float64(k))
                k *= 2
        }

}
```

---

Output

```
jnml@fsc-r630:~/src/tmp$ go build && ./tmp && go version && uname -a
Bytes used for 1000 empty maps: 146816, bytes/map 146.8
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 1 entries: 147040, bytes/map 147.0
Bytes per entry 0.2
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 2 entries: 147040, bytes/map 147.0
Bytes per entry 0.1
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 4 entries: 247136, bytes/map 247.1
Bytes per entry 25.1
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 8 entries: 439056, bytes/map 439.1
Bytes per entry 36.5
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 16 entries: 818688, bytes/map 818.7
Bytes per entry 42.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 32 entries: 1194688, bytes/map 1194.7
Bytes per entry 32.7
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 64 entries: 2102976, bytes/map 2103.0
Bytes per entry 30.6
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 128 entries: 4155072, bytes/map 4155.1
Bytes per entry 31.3
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 256 entries: 6698688, bytes/map 6698.7
Bytes per entry 25.6
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 512 entries: 14142976, bytes/map 14143.0
Bytes per entry 27.3
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 1024 entries: 51349184, bytes/map 51349.2
Bytes per entry 50.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 2048 entries: 102467264, bytes/map 102467.3
Bytes per entry 50.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 4096 entries: 157214816, bytes/map 157214.8
Bytes per entry 38.3
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 8192 entries: 407031200, bytes/map 407031.2
Bytes per entry 49.7
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 16384 entries: 782616864, bytes/map 782616.9
Bytes per entry 47.8
go version devel +83b0b94af636 Sat Mar 09 16:25:30 2013 +1100 linux/amd64
Linux fsc-r630 3.2.0-38-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:18:21 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jnml@fsc-r630:~/src/tmp$
```

It's nice to see the numbers are better (by a factor of about 4x). The numbers for the release version (1.0.3) are only slightly higher:

```
jnml@fsc-r630:~/src/tmp$ go build && ./tmp
Bytes used for 1000 empty maps: 144192, bytes/map 144.2
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 1 entries: 144192, bytes/map 144.2
Bytes per entry 0.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 2 entries: 144192, bytes/map 144.2
Bytes per entry 0.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 4 entries: 315648, bytes/map 315.6
Bytes per entry 42.9
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 8 entries: 436288, bytes/map 436.3
Bytes per entry 36.5
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 16 entries: 885824, bytes/map 885.8
Bytes per entry 46.4
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 32 entries: 1331264, bytes/map 1331.3
Bytes per entry 37.1
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 64 entries: 2292800, bytes/map 2292.8
Bytes per entry 33.6
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 128 entries: 4935920, bytes/map 4935.9
Bytes per entry 37.4
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 256 entries: 12164160, bytes/map 12164.2
Bytes per entry 47.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 512 entries: 29887808, bytes/map 29887.8
Bytes per entry 58.1
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 1024 entries: 56840768, bytes/map 56840.8
Bytes per entry 55.4
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 2048 entries: 108736064, bytes/map 108736.1
Bytes per entry 53.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 4096 entries: 184368752, bytes/map 184368.8
Bytes per entry 45.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 8192 entries: 431340576, bytes/map 431340.6
Bytes per entry 52.6
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 16384 entries: 815378816, bytes/map 815378.8
Bytes per entry 49.8
jnml@fsc-r630:~/src/tmp$
```

Comment: The lowest number so far is 36.5 bytes/entry. The best hashmap one I know of is sparsehash, which has only 2 bits/entry. In comparison, even in the best case, Go has about 150x overhead.

Comment: However there is a huge variation in all "experimental" setups. Also a huge difference between ReadMemStats and /proc/self/statm. This at least means there is the per-entry cost _and_ some other hidden cost that depends on the number of entries, which broadens the question.

Comment: @JohnSmith Realy storing 24 bits in 2 bits? ;-) The difference between ReamMemStats and /proc/self/statm is expected. It's one of the flaws in Nick's approach. Ad variations: they are expected as well, the question is in the variance - I measured multiple times and it seems to be in few % only. Also: the lowest number is not 36.5, but 25.1. And last but not least: I can build a map with zero amortized space overhead simply by trading time for space used. There is a tuning knob in this and it is not set to one of the limits.

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, I'm talking about overheads in the whole thread. And yes, really. See for yourself https://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/
Variantions are expected? The important thing is variance? You think there is a random process going on here? hashmaps _grow_ this is what that extra overhead is. And they don't grow randomly, the algorithm is deterministic.

Comment: And now that I look at it again, the lowest number is not 25.1 either, it is 0.0, which is downright wrong because if you look at the source code, the lower bound is 9 bytes/per entry.
I don't think your results are reliable.

Comment: @JohnSmith I really don't need to look at any code to know for sure that no one can store 24 arbitrary bits using 2 bits only. There's a well known proof for this not being possible ;-) Variance _is_ expected and random/undeterministic/unpredictable things _are_ involved all over this code. Actually up to the, in the limit, of no guarantee that the program will ever reach completion B-) (The more realistic sources are e.g. any kind of I/O and goroutine scheduling. No goroutines involved in the code above, one may think. But that's not true, the runtime has it own as well.)

Comment: @JohnSmith: No, the zeros don't apply as bytes per item. They're only a _difference_ between 0 item and 2 item map sizes. It indicates optimization (preallocation I suppose) for very small maps and switching the representation for more entries.

Comment: Just accept that you're wrong or show me which line in runtime.[ch] makes the overhead/entry random. I have no idea how you invent "24 bits overhead" either. Show me that proof you're talking about. And the fact that sparsehash has 2 bits/entry overhead won't be affect by your beliefs or proofs. I measured it, everyone else measured it. sprasehash is the real deal.

Comment: Really? So it's only natural that a map with 0 entries and a map with 2 entries occupy the same space? Anyway your set up is an empiric one, the output is inconsistent and your explanation to that inconsistency is "overhead per entry is just random, the important thing is variance" which is downright wrong. I regret up-voting it at all.

Comment: @JohnSmith Such conclusions are not based in logic. Yes, preallocation in containers is a common practice (of good coders which know why it is a good thing to do). No, the overhead per entry is _not_ random. Instead, the measured quantity is a total difference in consumed memory. This number varies as it may randomly include _other_ memory consumption, _not_ caused by the map. Frankly, so far, all of the objections presented show a lack of insight into what happens during the lifetime of a Go program (a pretty complex issue). I suggest to instead take a deeper look into the run time sources.

Comment: @JohnSmith Ah, I missed one more of yours comments. 24 bits are not _overhead_, but the _size_ of the key+value of the map in question (in the above code) and thus a lower limit to a bits/item in the map. The randomness is a misunderstanding on your side, see my previous comment. And no, you cannot correctly measure that any map consumes 2 bits to store a 24 bit item. You are confusing size of an item vs bytes consumed per item. The later includes the overhead, which of course has a lower limit of _zero_ bits. Nothing surprising in that (cf. vector used as a map with linear/binary search).

Comment: I'm not confusing anything at all. You're the one who's confusing things right and left: all I ever talked about way the _overhead per entry_. It was you who's introducing things like "24 bits of key+value" or "randomness".

Comment: And the randomness is due to your own faulty comprehension: _you_ tried explain the inconsistent overhead/entry, which is in reality due to growing map, by saying "random/undeterministic/unpredictable things are involved all over this code" and started talking about the memory used by runtime goroutine --which is again complete nonsense: do you really expect _anyone_ to believe that memory due to runtime goroutine increases unboundedly everytime you add new items to maps? It's you who needs to take a look into runtime sources, not me.

Comment: It's you who shows a lack of insight what happends during the life of a Go program, just take your own advice and take a look into runtime sources yourself before making outrageous claims like that.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't gotten "super awesome" results always usinhg google sparsehash, it would be interesting to run some tests against it for comparison, using the same sized keys/values as this.  Also note that sparsehash trades lookup speed for "memory size" so may be a slower lookup mechanism.

Comment: Just found this and ran the code on 1.14, result is: Bytes used for 1000 maps with 16384 entries: 181365080, bytes/map 181365.1
Bytes per entry 11.1

Comment: For what its worth, running this for a map of 64 bit values (ie: []*map[uint64]uint64), using Golang 1.14.5 on a 64-bit OS, showed a usage of 38.3 bytes per entry once a decent number of entries were added (32768 or more), which didn't change even when going up into the billions of entries. So for a quick shorthand, 1 million entries will use 38.3 MB.

Answer (score 3):

Overhead per map entry is not a constant value, since it depends on a number of buckets per map entry.

There is a great article on the map internals: https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2013/12/macro-view-of-map-internals-in-go.html

> The hash table for a Go map is structured as an array of buckets. The number of buckets is always equal to a power of 2.

...

> How Maps Grow
>
> As we continue to add or remove key/value pairs from the map, the efficiency of the map  lookups begin to deteriorate. The load threshold values that determine when to grow the  hash table are based on these four factors:
>
> % overflow  : Percentage of buckets which have an overflow bucket
>
> bytes/entry : Number of overhead bytes used per key/value pair
>
> hitprobe    : Number of entries that need to be checked when looking up a key
>
> missprobe   : Number of entries that need to be checked when looking up an absent key

For example a very simple benchmark can show a dramatic increase in overhead per entry when increasing number of entries just by 1:

```
func Benchmark(b *testing.B) {
    m := make(map[int64]struct{})

    // also resets mem stats
    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        m[int64(i)] = struct{}{}
    }
}
```

Benching with 106496 entries:

`go test -bench . -benchtime 106496x -benchmem
Benchmark-2       106495                65.7 ns/op            31 B/op          0 allocs/op`

e.g. 31 bytes per entry

Now increase the number of entries by one:

`go test -bench . -benchtime 106497x -benchmem
Benchmark-2       106497                65.7 ns/op            57 B/op          0 allocs/op`

e.g. 57 bytes per entry

Increasing the number of entries by 1 resulted in the doubling of the number of underlying buckets, which resulted in an additional overhead. The overhead will decrease when more entries are added, until the number of buckets is doubled again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is a buffer involved, and it grows only when needed. I can't tell for gccgo, though, I just tried it on the playground. Basically, it allocates 128 bytes for the empty map, then it grows when needed.

You can see it here : http://play.golang.org/p/RjohbSOq0x

Answer (score 2):

Here is an experiment to measure the overhead of maps.  Works under Linux only.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func ReadRss() int {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/proc/self/statm")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    rss, err := strconv.Atoi(strings.Fields(string(data))[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return rss * os.Getpagesize()
}

func main() {
    hs := []*map[byte]byte{}
    before := ReadRss()
    n := 10000
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        h := map[byte]byte{}
        hs = append(hs, &h)
    }
    after := ReadRss()
    empty_per_map := float64(after-before)/float64(n)
    fmt.Printf("Bytes used for %d empty maps: %d, bytes/map %.1f\n", n, after-before, empty_per_map)
    hs = nil
    runtime.GC()

    before = ReadRss()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        h := map[byte]byte{}
        for j := byte(0); j < 100; j++ {
            h[j] = j
        }
        hs = append(hs, &h)
    }
    after = ReadRss()
    full_per_map := float64(after-before)/float64(n)
    fmt.Printf("Bytes used for %d maps with 100 entries: %d, bytes/map %.1f\n", n, after-before, full_per_map)
    fmt.Printf("Bytes per entry %.1f\n", (full_per_map - empty_per_map)/100)

}
```

It prints this on my 64 bit Linux machine using go 1.0.3

```
Bytes used for 10000 empty maps: 1695744, bytes/map 169.6
Bytes used for 10000 maps with 100 entries: 43876352, bytes/map 4387.6
Bytes per entry 42.2
```

Or using go 1.0

```
Bytes used for 10000 empty maps: 1388544, bytes/map 138.9
Bytes used for 10000 maps with 100 entries: 199323648, bytes/map 19932.4
Bytes per entry 197.9
```

The memory measurements are done using the Linux OS rather than Go's internal memory stats. The memory measurements are coarse as they are returned in 4k pages, hence the large number of maps created.

So in round numbers each map costs about 170 bytes and each entry costs 42 bytes using go 1.0.3 (much more for 1.0)

Answer (score 1):

```
/*  Hal3 Mon Jul 18 20:58:16 BST 2016 go version go1.5.1 linux/amd64
Bytes used for 1000 empty maps: 0, bytes/map 0.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 1 entries: 112192, bytes/map 112.2
Bytes per entry 112.2
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 2 entries: 113472, bytes/map 113.5
Bytes per entry 56.7
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 4 entries: 110912, bytes/map 110.9
Bytes per entry 27.7
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 8 entries: 112192, bytes/map 112.2
Bytes per entry 14.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 16 entries: 231600, bytes/map 231.6
Bytes per entry 14.5
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 32 entries: 413768, bytes/map 413.8
Bytes per entry 12.9
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 64 entries: 736920, bytes/map 736.9
Bytes per entry 11.5
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 128 entries: 1419624, bytes/map 1419.6
Bytes per entry 11.1
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 256 entries: 2735192, bytes/map 2735.2
Bytes per entry 10.7
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 512 entries: 5655168, bytes/map 5655.2
Bytes per entry 11.0
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 1024 entries: 10919888, bytes/map 10919.9
Bytes per entry 10.7
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 2048 entries: 21224528, bytes/map 21224.5
Bytes per entry 10.4
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 4096 entries: 42391024, bytes/map 42391.0
Bytes per entry 10.3
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 8192 entries: 84613344, bytes/map 84613.3
Bytes per entry 10.3
Bytes used for 1000 maps with 16384 entries: 169152560, bytes/map 169152.6
Bytes per entry 10.3
Mon Jul 18 20:58:25 BST 2016 */
```